# Raspberry Pi Pianobar PulseAudio

Tags: raspberry-pi, pulseaudio, pandora

I have been trying to get pianobar working on my Raspberry Pi. I built version 2013.05.19-dev from Github and it works when I have `/etc/libao.conf` `default_driver=alsa`. The problem is that this gives horrible quality audio. I followed the instructions for installing PulseAudio and MPD [on dbader's blog](http://dbader.org/blog/crackle-free-audio-on-the-raspberry-pi-with-mpd-and-pulseaudio). Now when I set `default_driver=pulse`, pianobar tells me `/!\ Cannot open audio device`. I have been looking for a solution to this so any tips or help would be great!

Comment: Does Pulse work as a driver when you build it in a similar way on a non-raspberry-pi system?  Does it work with any other software within the raspberry pi?

Comment: Pulse seems to be working on an HP laptop I have running Ubuntu. It also seems to be able to play the hello_audio.bin on the RPi. However, pianobar spits out the same error when I try to use it as the default driver.